# Getting mouse event is not abstract error

Tags: java, mouseevent, abstract

So i have this code and everytime i compile it i get the *error: MouseEvent is not abstract and does not override abtract method mouseExited.*

can anyone tell me why or how to fix it.

`

```
import javax.swing.*;

import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

import javax.swing.event.MouseInputListener;

import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

public class MouseEvent extends JFrame implements MouseInputListener {

JLabel label = new JLabel("Label");
//constructor
public MouseEvent() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    getContentPane().add(panel);

    setSize(800,400);
    setVisible(true);
}//end constructor

//main method
public static void main(String args[]){
    new MouseEvent();

}//end main method

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    label.setText("Mouse Clicked");
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
    label.setText("Mouse Entered");
}
 public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
    label.setText("Mouse Entered");
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    label.setText("moyse held");
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
    label.setText("mouse released");
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
    label.setText("Mouse Dragged");
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
    label.setText("mouse moved");
}
```

}//end class`

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the name of your class to avoid collision with java's MouseEvent class.

Comment: That won't fix the error, though it is good advice.  (EDIT) never mind, that's actually the problem.